# R - Create and populate new column in dataframe using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

My eventual goal is to plot data points where their colors correspond to an altitude (original data is a column in a .csv file). I've created a dataframe with the altitude column, and I'm now trying to make a new column that assigns colors as the altitude increases. The range is from 0-400, so I wanted to change the color every 50 feet.

```
e_miss_df$color <- ""
for (i in nrow(e_miss_df$e_miss.altitude.feet.)) {
  if (i <= 50.0){
    n <- "#00A600FF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else if (i <= 100.0) {
    n <- "#3EBB00FF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else if (i <= 150.0) {
    n <- "#8BD000FF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else if (i <= 200.0){
    n <- "#E6E600FF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else if (i <= 250.0) {
    n <- "#E8C32EFF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else if (i <= 300.0) {
    n <- "#EBB25EFF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else if (i <= 350.0) {
    n <- "#EDB48EFF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else if (i <= 400.0) {
    n <- "#F0C9C0FF"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
}  else {
    n <- "black"
    e_miss_df$color[i] <- n
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the column doesn't get filled (except at the 6th row??). I know it's incredibly inefficient right now, but I'm pretty new still... Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! And if you have a better way to get the plot, that'd be great too haha

Comment: Try with `for (i in 1:nrow(e_miss_df$e_miss.altitude.feet.)){...`. The delimiter of you loop is not correct because the beginning of the loop, presumably `1:`, is missing; irrespective of whether there are better ways to program this. In your loop you were not really looping, but instead only checking the last entry, i.e., the case `i=nrow(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

In R you typically want to work on the whole dataframe and avoid looping. You could try something like this:

```
#function that will assign color based on values
definecolor <- function(x) {
  color = "black"
  if (x <= 50)  color <- "#00A600FF"
  if (x <= 100) color <- "#3EBB00FF"
  if (x <= 150) color <- "#8BD000FF"
  if (x <= 200) color <- "#E6E600FF"
  if (x <= 300) color <- "#EBB25EFF"
  if (x <= 350) color <- "#EDB48EFF"
  if (x <= 400) color <- "#F0C9C0FF"
  return(color)
}

#apply that function to all values in a column and put those values in the new column
e_miss_df$color <- lapply(definecolor, e_miss_df$e_miss.altitude.feet.)

# you can also use ggplot to get intervals directly. something like this:
df <- data.frame(x = c(50,100,150,200,300,350,400), y=x)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=x, color=cut_interval(y,6))) + geom_point()
```